# YCSB not able to load data into cassandra multinode

Tags: cassandra, ycsb

I am trying to load data using YCSB tool into cassandra multinode set up, using the below command.

```
./ycsb  load cassandra-10 -P ../workloads/workloadb -s
```

but I am getting the following output.
I put the hosts parameter in workload as server's IP address.

P.S. I am able to successfully create multinode set-up and created db 'usertable' with table 'data'

```
2014-12-02 02:55:25:013 0 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:55:35:014 10 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:55:45:015 20 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:55:55:016 30 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:56:05:017 40 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:56:15:018 50 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:56:25:019 60 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:56:35:020 70 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:56:45:020 80 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:56:55:021 90 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:57:05:023 100 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:57:15:024 110 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:57:25:024 120 sec: 0 operations; 
2014-12-02 02:57:35:025 130 sec: 0 operations;
```

Comment: Getting this error at the end.
UnavailableException()
 at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:16485)
 at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:916)
 at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:890)
 at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.insert(CassandraClient10.java:477)
 at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.insert(DBWrapper.java:148)
 at com.yahoo.ycsb.workloads.CoreWorkload.doInsert(CoreWorkload.java:461)
 at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:277)

Answer (score 0):

```
    /root/ycsb-0.1.4/bin/ycsb load cassandra-10 -p hosts="<ip1> <ip2> <ip3> .." -p port=9160 -p recordcount=1000000 -P /root/ycsb-0.1.4/workloads/workloada -s
```

you need to put IP adddress of all the seed nodes in the host parameter which u provided in yaml file.